# Is there an alternative to the Hough circle transform (GHTG) I could use for my difficult case?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

**EDIT**: I found [ELSD](http://ubee.enseeiht.fr/vision/ELSD/) and am going to give it a shot, but any advice would still be appreciated.

**EDIT2**: The online demo of ELSD works nicely on this problem but the source is in C. Porting it is beyond me.

I am trying to detect postmarks on vintage postcards such as these:

[image]

[image]

I can spend a few minutes to tweak the cv2.HoughCircles parameters until the postmark is one of a few circles detected... for one scan, but the next card needs entirely different parameters to detect its postmark. At this point, it would a few be orders of magnitude faster to do this manually.

Part of the problem is that the handwriting is often detected as circles, I assume when enough of the curves in the cursive happen to have a similar center point. For whatever radius ranges I use to discriminate there always seems to be **something** in the handwriting that is detected as a false positive.

Another problem is that the circle often overlaps with other things, such as the stamp or handwriting.

Lastly, the circle part of the stamp is more often than not incomplete.

Is there an alternative to the GHTG method I could use? Perhaps something that checks how much of a continuous circular arc is present without interruption? (While the mark circles are often incomplete, they usually have at least pi radians visible.) Or something that checks for perfect circularity? Less efficient is just fine, as long as it reliably detects real partial-circles without (m)any false positives.